# java-fx installing in eclipse which command?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, javafx

I am using c++ on eclipse through ubuntu.
Now I have a code which I need to use java-fx for.
I have downloaded the following folder:

```
 jdk-8u65-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

I have the following folder right now:
location:

```
 /tmp/jdk1.8.0_65
```

relevant folder names in this location:

```
  javafx-src.zip    bin   jre    lib     src.zip
```

question is, how do I download this to my eclipse?
I don't know which command to use and I am on it for an hour..
...HELP??